# PHP password crypt giving weird results

Tags: php, mysql, crypt

I have had a weird result when testing my login.
When I use the password "100percent", the following output is displayed

> ltu1GUwy71wHk = ltu1GUwy71wHk

If I use the password `100percenttest`, I get the same output.

How can two different passwords give the same results?

```
//Get login Details
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);
$deviceID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['deviceID']);
$model = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['model']);
$platform = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['platform']);
$version = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['version']);
$password = crypt($password, "MYSALT");

//Check login details
$loginQuery = "SELECT * FROM tblMember WHERE Username='$username'";
$loginResult = mysql_query($loginQuery);
$loggedIn = false;
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loginResult))
{   
echo $row['Password'] . "=" . $password . "<BR/>";
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing the original password you get?

Comment: I hope you're not using one static salt, since that's missing the point of a salt. Use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/ for a proper implementation of `crypt` to hash passwords. You should also not be SQL-escaping the value before you hash it, but afterwards.

Comment: To be fair, it doesn't matter if you SQL escape it, since it's getting hashed anyway. (And of course, there's no need to escape the hash.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

> The standard DES-based crypt() returns the salt as the first two characters of the output. It also only uses the first eight characters of str, so longer strings
>       that start with the same eight characters will generate the same result (when the 
>       same salt is used).

You can prefix your salt with certain strings to force PHP to use a different algorithm (e.g., `$5$` to use SHA-256). Personally I recommend using Blowfish at a high number of rounds; consult the documentation for an example.

P.S. - You should not be using `mysql` in your PHP code, ever. Use the improved `mysqli` extension instead.

Comment: This is solved... The function crypt() only uses the first 8 characters. Anything more is ignored. So a password of 12345678 gets the same result as 1234567890